# is $("#File_Selector_Container").html(data); synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is `$("#File_Selector_Container").html(data);` synchronous?

Basically, will the DOM will have finished being updated once this completes so that I can refer to elements in the HTML that is in `data` following this statement?

Comment: Yes, this is completely synchronous.

Comment: Yes, DOM read/write is synchronous. If you think about this it can't be asynch because DOM tree would be unstable, different every time.